# Run function exactly once for each row in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, function, numpy, pandas

If I have a function

```
def do_irreversible_thing(a, b):
    print a, b
```

And a dataframe, say

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)], columns=['a', 'b'])
```

What's the best way to run the function **exactly once** for each row in a pandas dataframe.  [As](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635915/why-does-pandas-apply-calculate-twice) pointed out in other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857895/working-around-pandas-bug-that-iterates-over-an-imaginary-row-of-a-dataframe-wit), something like df.apply pandas will call the function twice for the first row.  Even using numpy

```
np.vectorize(do_irreversible_thing)(df.a, df.b)
```

causes the function to be called twice on the first row, as will `df.T.apply()` or df.apply(..., axis=1).

Is there a faster or cleaner way to call the function with every row than this explicit loop?

```
   for idx, a, b in df.itertuples():
       do_irreversible_thing(a, b)
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for a `for` loop. There generally isn't a good way to vectorize side effects.

Comment: If the side effects don't depend on the operation for each row then it should be vectorizable

Comment: If you need to run an explicit loop, you may get better performance with `zip(df.a, df.b)` or `df.itertuples()`, as detailed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34311080/3339965).

Answer (score 16):

The way I do it (because I also don't like the idea of looping with df.itertuples) is:

```
df.apply(do_irreversible_thing, axis=1)
```

and then your function should be like:

```
def do_irreversible_thing(x):
    print x.a, x.b
```

this way you should be able to run your function over each row.

**OR**

if you can't modify your function you could `apply` it like this

```
df.apply(lambda x: do_irreversible_thing(x[0],x[1]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 8):

It's unclear what your function is doing but to `apply` a function to each row you can do so by passing `axis=1` to `apply` your function row-wise and pass the column elements of interest:

```
In [155]:
def foo(a,b):
    return a*b
​
df = pd.DataFrame([(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)], columns=['a', 'b'])
df.apply(lambda x: foo(x['a'], x['b']), axis=1)

Out[155]:
0     0
1     6
2    20
dtype: int64
```

However, so long as your function does not depend on the df mutating on each row, then you can just use a vectorised method to operate on the entire column:

```
In [156]:
df['a'] * df['b']

Out[156]:
0     0
1     6
2    20
dtype: int64
```

The reason is that because the functions are vectorised then it will scale better whilst the `apply` is just syntactic sugar for iterating on your df so it's a `for` loop essentially